# How do I access textField Value, which is created dynamically in Objective C using for loop?

Tags: objective-c

I have created 4 `UITextField` using for loop in Objective C. Now I want to validate those text. whether those text field is empty or not.

```
 for(int i=0;i<4; i++){

            UITextField   *textField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(x, y, 211, 39)];
            UIView *paddingView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 10, 20)];
            [textField setTag:i];
            textField.leftView = paddingView;
            textField.leftViewMode = UITextFieldViewModeAlways;
            textField.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:237.0/255.0 green:237.0/255.0 blue:237.0/255.0 alpha:1.0];
            textField.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:15];
            textField.placeholder = [placeholder objectAtIndex:i];
            textField.autocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo;
            textField.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeDefault;
            textField.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyDone;
            textField.clearButtonMode = UITextFieldViewModeWhileEditing;
            textField.contentVerticalAlignment = UIControlContentVerticalAlignmentCenter;
            if(i>=2){
                [textField setSecureTextEntry:YES];
            }
             [self.view addSubview:textField];
            y=y+69;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can retrieve textfields like below with tag value.

```
UITextField *txtField1 = [self.view viewWithTag:0];
UITextField *txtField2 = [self.view viewWithTag:1];
UITextField *txtField3 = [self.view viewWithTag:2];
UITextField *txtField4 = [self.view viewWithTag:3];
UITextField *txtField5 = [self.view viewWithTag:4];

if(txtField1.text.length > 0)
{

}
```

Same check you can apply for other textfields.

Note:
 Make sure you have unique tag values rather than 0,1,2,3,4,5.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check if your `UITextField` is empty, define a `macro` for trimming the whitespaces.

```
#define TRIM(string) [string stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet]]
```

In your button action method.

```
UITextField *textField1 = [self.view viewWithTag:0];
UITextField *textField2 = [self.view viewWithTag:1];
UITextField *textField3 = [self.view viewWithTag:2];
UITextField *textField4 = [self.view viewWithTag:3];

if(![TRIM(textField1.text) length])
{
   // Your textfield is empty 
}
//Similarly check for other textfields
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for(int i=0;i<4; i++) {
    UITextField   *textField = [self.view viewWithTag:i];
    if (textField.hasText) {
        //If this returns true then text field has text otherwise not
    }
}
```

This will automatically manage whitespaces.